# React native how to change ProgressBarAndroid start color and end color

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use `ProgressBarAndroid` component of `react-native`. I want progress area color and remind area color different. Please look at my code below:

```
 <ProgressBarAndroid
                styleAttr="Horizontal"
                color="#FFC300"
                progress={this.state.width}
                indeterminate={false}
                style={{ width: this.state.totalWidth }}
         />
```

Please see below screenshot when applying above code:

[image]

PS: [Original screenshot of progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHQLJ.png)

Comment: you want you progress bar  like  screenshot ?? or it iscoming like screenshot and you want completely diffrent colors?

Comment: Hi, @abhinandansharma above screenshot progress bar is coming when applying the progress bar code. I want two different colors.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find a way but this feature is not there in `ProgressBarAndroid`.

Instead of this you can try `react-native-progress` which provide you with options to selected colors according to your requirement.Below is the link of the library.

References: [github.com/oblador/react-native-progres](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress/blob/master/README.md)